# Can't Coalesce on Extent Aggregations with GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geodjango

When I try to `Coalesce` on `Extent` aggregations, 
I get a string instead of the expected 4-tuple.

To explain:

This works:

```
>>> Community.objects.annotate(extent=Extent('geometry')).get(...).extent
(2726459.05875, 1220672.3825, 2736397.89, 1227645.2375)
```

as well as this:

```
>>> Community.objects.annotate(extent=Extent('potential__geometry')).get(...).extent
(2726687.04049593, 1221917.0, 2732056.725, 1223760.94563836)
```

But when I use them together in a `Coalesce` call this doesn't work:

```
>>> Community.objects.annotate(extent=
... Coalesce(Extent('potential__geometry'), Extent('geometry'))).get(...).extent
'BOX(2726687.04049593 1221917,2732056.725 1223760.94563836)'
```

Neither does this

```
>>> Community.objects.annotate(extent=
... Coalesce(Extent('potential__geometry'), Extent('geometry'),
...     output_field=ExtentField())).get(...).extent
'BOX(2726687.04049593 1221917,2732056.725 1223760.94563836)'
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey, @Dan, I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Yes, but I haven't looked at this issue in a while

Comment: when you apply the answer let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `convert_value` of the [`Extent`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py#L39) method doesn't get called during the `Coalesce` call, like it returns the first not null objects from the left without letting it finish the whole process... 
This is very strange indeed and probably the @django team should be notified (it maybe by design, so at least they can clarify on the subject!)

---

In the mean time you can work around the issue with one of the following ways:

1. Create your own `convert_value` function:

   ```
   def my_convert_value(value):
       value = value[4:-1] 
       box_min, box_max = value.split(',') 
       xmin, ymin = map(int, box_min.split())
       xman, ymax = map(int, box_max.split())
       return (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
   ```

   and that:

   ```
   my_convert_value(
       Community.objects.annotate(
           extent=Coalesce(
               Extent('potential__geometry'), 
               Extent('geometry')
       )).get(...).extent
   )
   ```

   will return:

   ```
   (2726687.04049593, 1221917.0, 2732056.725, 1223760.94563836)
   ```
2. Omit the usage of `Coalesce` and replace it with this:

   ```
   from django.db.models import CharField, Case, Value, When

   Community.objects.annotate(
       extent=Extent(
           Case(
               When(
                   potential__geometry__isnull=False,
                   then=Value('potential__geometry'),
               ),
               When(
                   geometry__isnull=False,
                   then=Value('geometry'),
               ),
               default=Value('geometry'),
               output_field=CharField(),
           )
       )
   ).get(...).extent
   ```

   **Explanation:**

   - The `Extent()` method expects as argument the name of a geometry
     column.
   - `Coalesce` returns the value of the first not null field from left to right.
   - Utilizing django [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) we create a `Coalesce`-like method **which returns the name of the first column that is not null**, or `'geometry'` as a default.
   - Finally we apply `Extent` on the column that the previous returns.

If I find anything else I will let you know!